# Facebook article sharing from mobile device

Tags: facebook, sharing

I understand that sharing article from desktop can utilize the following URL

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=http://www.yoururlhere.com&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://www.urltoyourimage.com
```

However, when I opened the URL in Ipad or mobile, I am getting an error saying "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

An alternative is to use m.facebook.com/sharer.php, but it seems that the parameter that I can use here is limited (I cannot specify the title or image).

Any hint on how I can share an article from mobile devices and getting it similar as the one using www.facebook.com/sharer.php ?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The only property that I can see that the mobile sharer accepts is "u" for url

i.e. http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.lagan-press.org.uk

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=http://www.yoururlhere.com&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://www.urltoyourimage.com
```

Use `m.facebook.com`, not `www.facbook.com`.